# which one of the following probability mass function can define a probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

> a) $f(x)=(5-x^2)/6$ for $x=0,1,2,3$
>   b) $f(x)=x/15$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5$
>   c) $f(x)=1/2^x$  for $x=0,1,2,3,4$
>   d) $f(x)=1/4$  for $x=2,3,4,5,6$

Can you please suggest me how to solve these questions ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Since you're new here, I wanted to let you know that it's a good idea to share your thoughts and attempts at any problems that you post here. This helps us to better tailor our answers to your needs. Also, in many cases, people find that the very act of explaining their thoughts helps them figure out the problem for themselves!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The probabilities should sum to 1 and all be non-negative. Which of your alternatives satisfy these two conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be a valid probability mass function it must satisfy $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ and $$\sum_{x\in\, \mathrm{supp}_f} f(x)=1,$$where $\mathrm{supp}_f=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)>0\}$.